# Why isn't Guzzle's concurrent request feature faster?

Tags: php, concurrency, httprequest, guzzle

I am trying to speed up a script by using Guzzle's concurrent request feature however the two scripts I have seem to take the same amount of time.

I have two php scripts that just pull the last 100 posts from a user's instagram account with the purpose of getting the embed code for each post.  Instagram has a limit of 20 posts per requests so it loops through 5 times.  Instagram also uses oembed so once I pull each post url I have to send it to their oembed endpoint to receive back the appropriate html.

In the original script, not using concurrent requests, it pulls the 100 post urls and then loops through requesting the oembed data.

```
public function getinstagramPosts2($instagram_id,$token)
{
    $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/' . $instagram_id . '/media/recent/';

    $urlparams = [
        'access_token' => $token,
    ];

    $count = 0;

    for($i=1 ; $i<6; $i++)
    {
        $response = $this->getURLResponse($url, $urlparams);

        foreach ($response['data'] as $instapost)
        {
            $url = 'http://api.instagram.com/publicapi/oembed/?url=' . $instapost['link'];

            $embedresponse = $this->getURLResponse($url);

            $posts[$count]['html'] = $embedresponse['html'];

            $count++;

        }
        if(isset($response['pagination']['next_url']))
        {
            $url = $response['pagination']['next_url'];
        }else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return $posts;
}
```

In the second script it pulls the 100 posts then uses Guzzle's concurrent request feature to load up the oembed requests and run them in parallel.

```
public function getinstagramPosts($instagram_id,$token)
{
    $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/' . $instagram_id . '/media/recent/';

    $urlparams = [
        'access_token' => $token,
    ];

    $count = 0;

    for($i=1 ; $i<6; $i++)
    {
        $response = $this->getURLResponse($url, $urlparams);

        foreach ($response['data'] as $instapost)
        {

            $url = 'http://api.instagram.com/publicapi/oembed/?url=' . $instapost['link'];

            $promises[$count] = $this->getHttpClient()->getAsync($url);

            $count++;

        }
        if(isset($response['pagination']['next_url']))
        {
            $url = $response['pagination']['next_url'];
        }else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    $results = Promise\unwrap($promises);

    $count = 0;

    foreach($results as $result)
    {

        $body = json_decode($result->getBody(),true);

        $posts[$count]['html'] = $body['html'];

        $count++;
    }

    return $posts;

}
```

I would think this would cut down on the time significantly but it takes the same time as the original script.  Why would that be?  What am I missing?  Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the primary reason for the lack of a time differential has to do with how you are processing the responses.  In the first example your requests and responses are being performed sequentially.  Perform a request, receive a response, process it.  In the second example, you perform your requests, wait for all responses, and then process the responses sequentially.  Assuming that the processing of the responses is identical, your only time difference would be the result of performing the requests asynchronously.

Having said that, you might see better results with [GuzzleHttp\Pool](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#concurrent-requests).  I've had good results with it.  Your particular case may vary.